# How to make view cache unlimited in cakephp 4.x

Tags: caching, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to enable caching for my site

enable cahe in bootstrap file but /tmp/views is always empty

*thank you*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no view caching anymore in CakePHP, it has been dropped ever since CakePHP 3.

You can use for example a caching proxy like [**Varnish**](https://varnish-cache.org/), or a CakePHP plugin like **[dereuromark/cakephp-cache](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-cache)**, or implement your own caching solution. If you only need to partially cache views, look into [**caching elements**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views.html#caching-elements).

See also

- **[Cookbook > Appendices > 3.0 Migration Guide > CacheHelper Removed](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#cachehelper-removed)**
- **[Awesome CakePHP > Caching](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#caching)**